# Shopify - Get Most Popular Articles

Tags: blogs, shopify

I'm creating a blog sidebar that will display the most popular articles.
I want to based the popularity of an article on views or Facebook comment count.

Since I'm editing an existing shop, what is the best way to implement this with minimal code change?
Is there an existing function or property for blog/article object that I can manipulate to achieve this, even only the for view count?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have comments enabled for the blog? If so, you could use [`article.comments_count`](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/objects/article#article-comments_count) to sort the articles by popularity.

Comment: Hi Steph, unfortunately we do intend to have the traffic of the site from the views or social media. So no, the comments_count is not an option. Thanks anyway! :)